# WolframAlpha Incorrect Result When Multiplying An Inverse By Another Matrix

Tags: wolfram-alpha

According to Wolfram Alpha, $\begin{bmatrix}3 & 1 \\ 5 & 2\end{bmatrix}^{-1}\begin{bmatrix}1 & 0 \\ 0 & 1\end{bmatrix}\neq \begin{bmatrix}3 & 1 \\ 5 & 2\end{bmatrix}^{-1}$.

Links to the two computations:

[MatrixPower[{{3, 1}, {5, 2}}, -1] {{1, 0}, {0, 1}}](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i2d=true&i=Power%5B%7B%7B3%2C1%7D%2C%7B5%2C2%7D%7D%2C-1%5D%7B%7B1%2C0%7D%2C%7B0%2C1%7D%7D)

[MatrixPower[{{3, 1}, {5, 2}}, -1]](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i2d=true&i=Power%5B%7B%7B3%2C1%7D%2C%7B5%2C2%7D%7D%2C-1%5D)

To further confuse things, leaving out the inverse produces the expected result ($\begin{bmatrix}3 & 1 \\ 5 & 2\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}1 & 0 \\ 0 & 1\end{bmatrix}= \begin{bmatrix}3 & 1 \\ 5 & 2\end{bmatrix}$):

[{{3, 1}, {5, 2}} . {{1, 0}, {0, 1}}](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i2d=true&i=%7B%7B3%2C1%7D%2C%7B5%2C2%7D%7D%7B%7B1%2C0%7D%2C%7B0%2C1%7D%7D)

Comment: The first link is broken.

Comment: Thanks, fixed it.

Answer (score 3):

It turns out you need to explicitly add a period between them in the input, otherwise, it does elementwise multiplication. For some reason, it automatically adds this in the third link provided in the question.

[MatrixPower[{{3, 1}, {5, 2}}, -1] . {{1, 0}, {0, 1}}](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i2d=true&i=Power%5B%7B%7B3%2C1%7D%2C%7B5%2C2%7D%7D%2C-1%5D.%7B%7B1%2C0%7D%2C%7B0%2C1%7D%7D)